# Javascript wont print my iFrame

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, linq

Im running a C# asp.net website. Cashiers generate vouchers by inputting an amount into a text box on a sales page.

When the generate button is clicked, it makes a call to the DB to input and retrieve information, once all of the DB inserting is done this information is then passed to an iFrame, as soon as the iFrame visability = true just the contents of the iFrame should print. i am using javascript to print the focused iFrame. It used to work but now just stopped working for no apparent reason.

please could someone help me find the problem.

**Sales Button Click**

```
rotected void btnVoucherGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["LoggedMemberID"] == null)
        {
            Session.Clear();
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            //Session.Remove("VoucherInfo");
            Cashiers _cashier = (Cashiers)Session["CashierInfo"];
            if (tbGeneratePIN.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                lblVoucherPIN.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblVoucherPIN.Text = "Please insert a amount for the voucher";
            }
            else
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(tbGeneratePIN.Text) < 5)
                {
                    lblVoucherPIN.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    lblVoucherPIN.Text = "Minimum amount is " + _cashier.currencySymbol + " 5.00";
                }
                else
                {
                    iThNkContext.Prepaid pre = new iThNkContext.Prepaid();

                    String newID = "";
                    newID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
                    newID = newID.Substring(newID.Length - 16);
                    newID = newID.ToUpper();

                    // Add PIN to Prepaid DB
                    try
                    {
                        btnVoucherGenerate.Visible = false;
                        btnGenerateAnother.Visible = true;
                        tbGeneratePIN.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                        tbGeneratePIN.Enabled = false;


                        pre.CurrencyID = _cashier.currencyID;
                        pre.AccountID = _cashier.accountID;
                        pre.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(tbGeneratePIN.Text);
                        pre.SerialNumber = ("_");
                        pre.Pin = newID;
                        pre.TransactionTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Voucher"]);
                        pre.SalesUserID = _cashier.userID;
                        pre.SiteID = _cashier.siteID;
                        pre.SalesDate = DateTime.Now;
                        pre.IsCancelled = false;
                        pre.IsPrinted = false;
                        pre.IsActivated = true;
                        pre.IsRedeemed = false;
                        pre.IsActive = true;

                        db.Prepaids.InsertOnSubmit(pre);
                        db.SubmitChanges();

                        pre.SerialNumber = Convert.ToString(pre.PrepaidID).PadLeft(9, '0');
                        db.SubmitChanges();

                        String SegmentedOTP = newID;
                        SegmentedOTP = SegmentedOTP.Substring(0, 4) + "-" +
                                       SegmentedOTP.Substring(4, 4) + "-" +
                                       SegmentedOTP.Substring(8, 4) + "-" +
                                       SegmentedOTP.Substring(12, 4);

                        // Log successful voucher sale.
                        _logs.successfulVoucherSales(_cashier.accountID, _cashier.siteID, _cashier.userID, pre.SerialNumber, pre.Pin, pre.Amount, _cashier.username);
                        Voucher _voucher = new Voucher();

                        _voucher.prepaidID = pre.PrepaidID;
                        _voucher.amount = pre.Amount;
                        _voucher.serialNumber = pre.SerialNumber;
                        _voucher.segmentedOTP = SegmentedOTP;
                        _voucher.accountTerms = pre.Account.AccountTerms.ToString();
                        _voucher.isPrinted = false;

                        Session["VoucherInfo"] = _voucher;

                        // update the database and set isPrinted = 1
                        db.SubmitChanges();
                        tbGeneratePIN.Text = string.Empty;

                        myIFrame.Visible = true;
                        pre.IsPrinted = true;
                        db.SubmitChanges();

                        lblVoucherPIN.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        lblVoucherPIN.Text = "Successful";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        lblVoucherPIN.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        lblVoucherPIN.Text = ex.Message;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**APSX**

```
<body id="Body">

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<link href="styles/Voucher.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <script type="text/javascript" >

     function PrintVoucher() {
         window.focus();
         window.print();
         return;
     }

</script>
    <table id="PrintTable" runat="server">
        <tr align="center" > 
            <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:0.1px solid black;padding-bottom:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" >
                <asp:Image ID="Logo" runat="server" Height="41px" ImageUrl="~/images/Logo.png" 
                    Width="247px" />
            </td> 
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="line-height:8px;padding:5px 0;" >
                <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text="SERIAL NUMBER:" Font-Names="Consolas" Font-Size="14px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td colspan="2" style="line-height:12px;padding-bottom:12px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblSerialNumber" runat="server" Font-Names="Consolas" Font-Size="24px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="line-height:8px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                <asp:Label ID="label2" runat="server" Text="PIN:" Font-Names="Consolas" Font-Size="14px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="line-height:12px;padding-bottom:12px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblPIN" runat="server" Font-Names="Consolas" Font-Size="24px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
       </tr>
       <tr> 
            <td colspan="2" style="line-height:8px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                <asp:Label ID="label3" runat="server" Text="AMOUNT:" Font-Names="Consolas" Font-Size="14px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:0.7px solid black;line-height:12px;padding-bottom:8px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Font-Names="Consolas" Font-Size="24px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="line-height:8px;" class="style1">
                <asp:Label ID="label5" runat="server" Text="Account: " Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="line-height:8px;height:0px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAccount" runat="server" Text="Supabets South Africa" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="line-height:8px;" class="style2">
                <asp:Label ID="label7" runat="server" Text="Site: " Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="line-height:8px;height:0px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSite" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="line-height:8px;" class="style2">
                <asp:Label ID="label6" runat="server" Text="Cashier: " Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="line-height:8px;height:0px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCashier" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="line-height:8px;padding-bottom:3px;" class="style1">
                <asp:Label ID="label8" runat="server" Text="Date: " Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="line-height:8px;padding-bottom:3px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:1.2px solid black;font-weight:bold; font-family:Consolas;font-size:20px;line-height:12px">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <%=Clients %>

</form>
```

**Voucher iFrame code behind**

```
public partial class VoucherInformation : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public string Clients { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Voucher _voucher = (Voucher)Session["VoucherInfo"];
        try
        {
            Cashiers _cashier = (Cashiers)Session["CashierInfo"];
            if (!_voucher.isPrinted)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_voucher.accountTerms))
                {
                    Clients = _voucher.accountTerms;
                }
                else
                {
                    Clients = "";
                }

                lblAmount.Text = _cashier.currencySymbol + " " + _voucher.amount + ".00";
                lblSerialNumber.Text = _voucher.serialNumber;
                lblPIN.Text = _voucher.segmentedOTP;
                lblSite.Text = _cashier.siteName;
                lblAccount.Text = _cashier.accountName;
                lblCashier.Text = _cashier.username;
                lblDate.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);

                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Print", "PrintVoucher();", true);

                _voucher.isPrinted = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _voucher.isPrinted = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "stopped working" mean? Does it print everything? Or nothing?

Comment: All the data gets inserted into my DB, but the vouchers just dont print.

Comment: I am using Silent printing aswel, so the print dialog box does not appear, all you see is the printer que that says the document is printing but it just doesnt print

Comment: I found the problem, the problem was not in my code.

in firefox's about:config i set silent printing = true, now after the last update i had to set silent print to false and then back to true.

Everything is working 100% now